# C# convert long datetime to get compatible with sql server datetime, date is coming from javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, sql-server, datetime

I am passing in a long date from javascript through web api and the date needs to be converted to end up being compatible with C# and then SQL Server datetime field.

This is What is getting passed in

```
Fri Sep 15 2017 00:11:44 GMT-0700 (US Mountain Standard Time
```

So I was just trying to do a `Convert.ToDateTime`

```
DateTime c = Convert.ToDateTime("Fri Sep 15 2017 00:11:44 GMT-0700 (US Mountain Standard Time)");
```

Says its not a valid DateTime,  and if I don't use convert , then error is that I cannot convert a long to a string.

This probably needs to first be converted in javascript as I think that it will blow up with C# DateTime

However `2017-09-15T07:11:44.000Z`  is not correct from javascript is it?

Comment: Where is your JS code? I think you can use `toISOString` method to convert JS date into given UTC format, then parse it in C#.

Answer (score 0):

From your example it also looks like you want to convert the local time into the equivalent GMT time. If this is the case, there's a great JavaScript library for date/time manipulation, [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-iso-string/), which will do that for you. `moment().toISOstring()` will take the JS user's current date time and give you a zulu time in ISO format.

Comment: security is so tight, I cannot use moment.js

Comment: I'd appreciate knowing why using moment.js is a security concern, if you don't mind sharing? I can't envision moment.js presenting any security concerns. You can look over the underlying code, which is freely available. You don't need to link to a third party site where it's hosted. (Can install on your own web server.) Etc. If you're worried about a client web user tinkering with the code, they can tinker with the data anyway in most browsers.

Comment: Cause I'm on a government contract and they have an anal security team blocking most 3rd party .   Already been yelled out.    contract job is paying well though ...   oh well

Answer (score 0):

```
string source = "Fri Sep 15 2017 00:11:44 GMT-0700";

var result = DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(
    source.Replace("GMT", ""), 
    "ddd MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz", 
    CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this piece of code to convert JavaScript long date to C# compatible format(dd/MM/yyyy):-

```
  var date = new Date();
  var newformateddate = function (date) {
  var year = date.getFullYear();
        var month = date.getMonth();
        month++;
        if (month < 10) {
            month = "0" + month;
        }


        var day = date.getDay();

        if (day < 10) {
            day = "0" + day;
        }

        document.write(day + " / " + month + " / " + year);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Parse datetime with formate is the base way to convert it.

```
DateTime.ParseExact(dateString.Substring(0,24),
                          "ddd MMM d yyyy HH:mm:ss",
                          CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```